# how to substitute a character from a range of values with itself plus another string?

Tags: bash

I am trying to substitute a character with itself, in a range, with the same character plus some other string. For example, let's say i have a file:

```
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0
& -0.461014 & 0.6485
& 2.795944 & 0.0094
& 0.989542 & 0.3312
```

In this case i will need to substitute 0 (line 3) with 0\\, 5 (line 4) with 5\\, 4 (line 5) with 4\\, and 2 (line 6) with 2\\.

Clearly, i can't use the "\n" as a pattern since it is found in all the lines of the file, while the substitutions should happen only for those lines which end with an integer in [0-9]. The pattern should then be `[0-9]\n`.

What i would do is something like:

`substitute [0-9]\n with [0-9]\\\\`

Maybe something like `sed`?

`sed 's/[0-9]\n/[0-9]\\\\/g'`

but of course it is not working, i.e. the output is the same as the input.

Expected results would be:

```
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

Comment: What you are trying to replace isn't `[0-9]`, but a line ending by `[0-9]`. The pattern should look something like this : `s/([0-9])$/\1\\$/`. You probably should add sed flags to handle capture groups

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, `it is not working` is rarely useful on a SO question. You should rather show your actual ouptut and explain how it is different from your expected output

Comment: @Aserre, yes, you're perfectly right about showing the output, my bad!

Comment: It's not clear what the pattern is. Perhaps `sed '/[^\]$/s/$/\\/' file`?

Comment: @tripleee added it!

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result

Comment: @markp-fuso done!

Comment: I mean, how do we know which lines to perform the replacement on? Anything which doesn't already end with a backslash? (That's what my earlier comment assumes.) The question talks about a range but never reveals what that range is. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee i don't understand. the question seems clear to me. there is an example, i specifically stated what needs to be "grepped" and the line number relative to the examples, the expected output, and an example of what the pattern to grep should be.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]$/,"& \\\\")} 1' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

or:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{$0=$0 " \\\\"} 1' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

or:

```
$ awk '!/ \\\\$/{$0=$0 " \\\\"} 1' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

or any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]$/& \\\\/' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

or:

```
$ sed '3,$s/$/ \\\\/' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

There are lots of other possibilities too.

Comment: i never used awk so i will stick to sed. do you have any reference to better understand how your examples work?

Comment: @gabt just the man page for each but I think it's pretty obvious what each does. Is there anything in particular you don't understand about any of the commands?

Comment: yes, i am aware that there is the man page for everything...what i was wondering, though, is how you created the regexp that you use, that is where the problems lie. but i guess i will need to ask a different question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `how you created the regexp`. Are you asking if I used some tool to figure out what an appropriate regexp would be for this? If so, no, I just typed it. If you're asking how did I figure out the regexp to use - `[0-9]$` is just the range of character(s) I want to match on (`[0-9]`) followed by the end of string indicator (`$`) (very much like one of your suggestions, `[0-9]\n` but there aren't newlines present in the string being compared since sed and awk read one line at a time by default) and similarly for the others.

Comment: what i mean is how you came up with this `& \\\\ ` in the first `sed` example assuming the `&` means `put here the same character that was grepped`, or  this `3,$s/$/ \\\\/` which to me is very exotic, to say the least, at it has the same effect of the `&` i just mentioned.  that's what i definitely need to work on.

Comment: In ```s/[0-9]$/& \\\\/``` - `&` is the string that matched the regexp, then there's a blank char and then ```\\\\``` because ```\``` is the "escape" meta-character used to make other metacharacters be treated literally so you need to escape **IT** too to make it literal - so to get 2 ```\```s in the output you need 4 ```\```s in the code. `3,$` just means "do the replacement from line 3 til the end of the file" and in `s/$/ \\\\/` the `$` means "the end of the string" (the line by default) so that's just appending 2 ```\```s to the end of each line no matter what char it ends with.

Comment: So in one script I'm skipping the first 2 lines by only matching on lines that end in a digit while in the other I'm specifically stating to start at line 3. The right script depends on your needs.

Comment: interesting, ok, thank you! i find it interesting you call them `scripts` too and not regex. by the way, thanks i will have a deeper look around.

Comment: A regexp is a very specific thing - it's just one type of pattern that can be used to try to match against strings. So `[0-9]$` is a regexp but it's useless unless used in a script such as `s/[0-9]$/,""/'`

Comment: yes, i think that's why i need to understand this `sed` better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, capture the last digit in a group and use that as the replacement with `\`:

```bash
$ sed -E 's/([0-9]$)/\1 \\\\/g' file
\hline \\
Value & Std.Error & DF & t-value & p-value \\
& 6.528616 & 0 \\
& -0.461014 & 0.6485 \\
& 2.795944 & 0.0094 \\
& 0.989542 & 0.3312 \\
```

Comment: i have a further question. is the `\1` telling sed that the character that was found is the one that should be used for substitution?

Comment: @gabt all Unix tools have manual pages. Type `man sed`.